# Is it possible to create custom ToolBarItems

Tags: wpf, toolbar, toolbaritems

I don't see a ToolBarItem class in msdn, and I notice that GetContainerForItemOverride() is not called on my derived ToolBar class.  Anyone know how to customize ToolBarItems?

Answer (score 1):

A `Toolbar` in WPF derives from `ItemsControl`. This means you can add arbitrary items to your toolbar, you do not need to derive from a specific class (other than `UIElement`).